# asmack BOSHConnection do not connect

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am developing android chat app using: `asmack-android-19-0.8.10.jar`

Server side is using BOSH protocol and send this kind of data:

```
{
    "Domain":"domain",
    "boshUrl":"http://domain:7070/http-bind/"
}
```

And I connect like this:

```
BOSHConfiguration  configuration = new BOSHConfiguration ("domain");
configuration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
BOSHConnection connectionBosh = new BOSHConnection (configuration);
connectionBosh.connect();
```

And I have got an XMPPException :
`Timeout reached for the connection to null:0.: remote-server-timeout(504)`

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!